# Yeoman giving permission errors even with sudo

Tags: azure, yeoman, azure-service-fabric, yo

I was following [this tutorial](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers-linux#package-the-docker-image-with-yeoman) and installed Yeoman and the Azure's generator.

So, when I did: `sudo yo azuresfcontainer`, it gives me the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:45
            throw err;
            ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/usr/lib/ssl/private'
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:875:3)
    at exports.readdir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/fs.js:18:20)
    at Object.safeCall [as safe] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/call.js:24:8)
    at DirectoryReader.readNextDirectory (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:78:10)
    at Readable.DirectoryReader.stream._read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:57:18)
    at Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:455:10)
    at readdirSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/index.js:27:21)
    at Function.readdirSyncStat (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/index.js:34:10)
    at ReaderSync.dynamicApi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:61:24)
    at ReaderSync.api (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:53:25)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at DirectoryReader.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:365:14)
    at call.safe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:81:14)
    at onceWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/call.js:45:17)
    at onceWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/call.js:45:17)
    at exports.readdir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/fs.js:22:5)
    at Object.safeCall [as safe] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/call.js:24:8)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at readdirSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/index.js:27:21)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you did anything wrong it looks like a dependency of yeoman broke yeoman.  It is the yeoman-environment dependency and this issue has been opened: https://github.com/yeoman/environment/issues/97 Copy pasting the issue below:

> While running yo, the following error occurs: Error: EACCES:
>   permission denied, scandir '/usr/sbin/authserver (MacOS / High Sierra)
>
> Culprit is here:
>
> ```
>   // Adds support for generator resolving when yeoman-generator has been linked
>   if (process.argv[1]) {
>         paths.push(path.join(path.dirname(process.argv[1]), '../..'));
>   }
> ```
>
> inside getNpmPaths(). My yo is at /usr/local/bin/yo, and this adds the
>   whole /usr directory to the search path => globby.sync inside
>   resolver.findsGeneratorIn will throw if some directories are not user
>   readable.
>
> Something like this fixes the issue:
>
> ```
> try {
>       modules = modules.concat(globby.sync(
>         ['generator-*', '@*/generator-*'],
>         {cwd: root, onlyFiles: false, absolute: true}
>       ));
> } catch(err) {
>      debug( 'Could not access %s (%s)', root, err); 
> }
> ```

I was able to workaround this by installing global packages to a different folder.  https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

> To minimize the chance of permissions errors, you can configure npm to
>   use a different directory. In this example, it will be a hidden
>   directory on your home folder.
>
> Back-up your computer before you start.
>
> Make a directory for global installations:
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/.npm-global
> ```
>
> Configure npm to use the new directory path:
>
> ```
> npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
> ```
>
> Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:
>
> ```
> export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
> ```
>
> Back on the command line, update your system variables:
>
> ```
> source ~/.profile
> ```
>
> Test: Download a package globally without using sudo.
>
> ```
> npm install -g jshint
> ```
>
> Instead of steps 2-4, you can use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g. if you don't want to modify ~/.profile):
>
> ```
> NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
> ```

Comment: yeoman-environment says "Released a new version with this fix."  So this should work now.